# how to prevent sequence generator from making primary key constraint violation exception?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sequence

I'm using sequence generator in oracle database with cache size 20 
and hibernate ,
sometimes I got **primary key constraint violation exception** .

imagine my table has the following ids :
1 ,
2,
50,
55,
1000,
1001

What I know, is that hibernate provide me with number of sequence to use them when persisting entities. In my case what I got is number of elements start from say 53. When I persisting the first entity it's okay because it will take 53 as id and there is no entity in my table with id =53 , the same for entity with 54, 
but when we got to 55 the **pk constraint violation** happen, so I added allocation size = 1 in sequence declaration in code. But I read that it's not good practice, because every time you persist entity you hit the database to get the next id and thus the idea of cashing is not taking place.

What should I do to preserve caching and not getting primary key violation exception?

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "someSeq", sequenceName ="SOME_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "someSeq")
private Integer id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are already rows in the database, you should set `SequenceGenerator`'s `initialValue`:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "someSeq", sequenceName ="SOME_SEQ", initialValue=1002)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="someSeq")
private Integer id;
```

Comment: as i know sequence generator makes gaps between ids so let us say if ten entities inserted they will take values after 1002 we don't know what they will be , then after that  when trying to insert another ten entites it will take 1200 as  initial value  and might cause the pk violation problem again i mean it doesn't guarantee uniquness at all if hibernate provide us with 10 sequences 5 of them may fauiler do you got my point ?? correct me please if i wrong

Comment: As long as the sequence is created it will not go back to an existing value. When JPA reserves e.g. 50 ids starting from 1200, the DB sequence is advanced by 50 positions, so points to 1250. The next time JPA needs to reserve ids from the database, it will start from 1250 so no overlaps can happen. Unless of course there is some other process inserting data without paying attention to the sequence or the sequence is deleted.

Comment: ok i got your point  but what is the difference between  the attribute start by :  1200 when creating the sequence itself in database and attribute initialvalue=1200 in code can attribute startby override what initialValue do or not because when i previously setting  startby with some value the same issue occured , you can clarify this by explaining to me the whole cycle from jpa to database

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'cache size 20'? `allocationSize` is not specified, so it is equal to 50 (the default).

Also, if your sequence starts at 53, how come an id of 1001 was even inserted in the first place? Did you insert the entry with a manually specified id/regenerated the table content from a script?

If ids can be inserted manually in your application, then no amount of tweaking the generator configuration can shield you from constraint violations. Instead, whenever you insert data into the table where the id values do not match what Hibernate *would have used*, you need to explicitly forward the sequence up to `MAX(ID) + allocationSize + 1`. How to do that depends on which database you're using.